# Static members need special synchronization blocks?

Tags: java, static, synchronization, locking

I have a class which looks something like this:

```
public class Test {

private static final Object someObject = new Object();

public void doSomething()
{
    synchronized (someObject) {
        System.out.println(someObject.toString());
    }
}

}
```

Can I consider the object to be synchronized, or is there a problem since it is a static member?

**Edit:** note that different threads might be accessing doSomething() and the object **must** be accessed in a thread-safe manner in that case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using a static object as your monitor object, only one thread using ANY instance of the Test class can get into the sync block.  If the monitor object was not a static object, other threads holding different instances of the Test class could get into the sync block.

Comment: I do not understand. Does this mean the code snippet works like I am expecting it?

Comment: I believe David's point is that by making it a static member, it introduces a possibility of a bottleneck, if lots of threads are expected to call that method.

Answer (score 4):

Here **someObject** is acting as a lock (monitor) for **all** objects of type Test.  That is, if doSomething() is invoked on two separate instances of Test, one will block before the other completes. This is different from a synchronized method which which is mostly equivalent to the code above with **someObject** replaced by **this**.

Changing **someObject** to non-static will result in per--instance locking. This is essentially the "private lock object" idiom as described in item 70 of *Effective Java*.

Answer (score 1):

A common pattern for getting a class-specific instance-independent lock like this is to use the Class object itself:

```
public class Test {
  public void doSomething() {
    synchronized (Test.class) {
      // something
    }
  }
}
```

which is effectively what a synchronized static method does.  Of course if you want more than one lock like this, you'll need to declare them as static fields as in your example.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if Test class is loaded using different classloaders?